# Force Vibration even when energy saver is on / vibration disabled

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-vibration

Is there any way to force vibrations even when it is "semi-disabled" in the Settings?

E.g. for an alarm that requires more than something visual.

Surprised that no one seems to have asked this yet